# Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer

Tags: sdk, .net-framework-version

I want to install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 .. so i should install .NET Framework 4 But there is an error i can't solve it ..
 [image: This Error]

i tried to uninstall installed .NET frame work from "Program and Features"
But I don't know which one to be uninstall .. and i'm afraid if another program use it 
[image]

Comment: That does not look like the Windows SDK installer.  At all.  If you don't tell us why you need it and what you've downloaded then it all gets to be but a guessing game.

Comment: it is .Net Framework 4 installer .. while i setup Windows SDK , it told me that i must install the RTM .Net Framework 4 first .. so am trying to install it

Answer (score 0):

**First we need to find the installed package. For that enable Windows Installer logging.**

1) In `run` open `gpedit.msc` or you can google how to open group policy editor

2) Expand in left panel `Computer Configuration -->Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Windows Installer`

3) On right panel open `Logging` and `Enable` it and in option Logging `voicewarmupx`

4) Restart your PC

**Now Windows Installer logging is enabled. Next we need to find and uninstall the conflicting package.**

1) Open windows `%temp%` (can be opened by typing %temp% in run) and delete all files. If something cant be deleted leave it.

2) Run the `.NET Framework 4 installer` again. After the installer fails, close it.

3) Open windows `%temp%` again and open the log file (file would be MSIxxxxx.LOG, eg:MSI232f1.LOG)

4) Search for a line saying `PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding NEWERVERSIONDETECTED property. Its value is {xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx}'.` Value will be different depending on the package that is already installed.

5) Open command prompt and run `msiexec /uninstall {xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx}`

6) Now try installing `.NET Framework 4 Installer` again. This time it will succeed.

**Also don't forget to disable `Windows Installer logging`. Using the same way you enabled it.**

Comment: this does not work anymore at win7. there are no MSI log file being generated.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if you allready installed .Net 4  in registry

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319